# Created a new array from another array. Need to sort the new one in the order of elements of the other array

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

so I am quite confused right now because I am new to bash and I am not sure how I am going to tackle this problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 H7 D7 C7 S6 H6 D6 C6 S5 H5 D5 C5 S4 H4 D4 C4 S3 H3 D3 C3 S2 H2 D2 C2)
declare -a cardsNamed

for i in "$@"
do

cardsNamed+=' '${cards[i]}

done

echo The hand is $cardsNamed
```

I need the $cardsNamed array to sort the cards in order of elements of the first array. For example if cardsNamed has SJ HA DK. It would sort to HA DK SJ.

For some background. This is a card game that displays the cards you pick through parsing the arguments and then sorts and discards pairs.

Really appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks

Comment: If `$@` is a set of numbers, why not sort it first? A `set -- $(printf "%d\n" "$@" | sort -n)` before the `for` loop, for example.

Comment: I need the unsorted list then the sorted below it. Thanks though, that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your arguments are numbers and valid indices to the array, I can think of two ways:

#### Sort the arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 H7 D7 C7 S6 H6 D6 C6 S5 H5 D5 C5 S4 H4 D4 C4 S3 H3 D3 C3 S2 H2 D2 C2)

for i
do
    cardsNamed+=' '${cards[i]}
done

set -- $(printf "%d\n" "$@" | sort -n)
for i
do
    cardsNamedSorted+=' '${cards[i]}
done

echo The hand is $cardsNamed
echo The sorted hand is $cardsNamedSorted
```

You could also do `for i in $(printf "%d\n" "$@" | sort -n)` instead of using `set`, if you don't want to overwrite the arguments.

#### A new array with only selected entries

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a cards=(null SA HA DA CA SK HK DK CK SQ HQ DQ CQ SJ HJ DJ CJ ST HT      DT CT S9 H9 D9 C9 S8 H8 D8 C8 S7 H7 D7 C7 S6 H6 D6 C6 S5 H5 D5 C5 S4 H4 D4 C4 S3 H3 D3 C3 S2 H2 D2 C2)
declare -a cardsNamedSorted

for i
do
    cardsNamed+=' '${cards[i]}
    cardsNamedSorted[i]=${cards[i]}
done

echo The hand is $cardsNamed
echo Sorted hand: "${cardsNamedSorted[@]}"
```

`cardsNamedSorted` will only contain the specified entries, in the same order as `cards`.

---

Notes:

- `for i` without an `in <something>` is the same as `for i in "$@"`.
- You have declared `cardsNamed` as an array, yet its usage is like a normal variable.